# PHP Close Code Block Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently receiving this error:

`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' - line 14, col 1`

In response to this code block:

```
    <?php
include_once("base.php");
if(empty($_GET)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM segth";
    $q = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>" . $r [1] . "</th></tr>
        <tr><td>$" . $r[2] . "</td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' id='u0name' placeholder='Adjust " . $r [1] . "s Cash' onKeyPress='preupd(event, 0)' /></td></tr></table>";
    }


    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        echo "<table class='norm' border='1'><tr><th>" . $r[1] . "</th></tr><tr><td>$" . $r[2] . "</td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' id='u0name' placeholder='Adjust " . $r [1] . "s Cash' onKeyPress='preupd(event, " . $r [1] . ")' /></td></tr></table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<h1 align='center'>New Game</h1>";
    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<8;$i++) {
                    echo "<tr><td><input id='u" . $i . "name' placeholder='Player " . ($i+1) . "s Name' /></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr><td><button value='Start' onClick='strt()'>Start</button></table>";
    }
    ?>
```

I have tried removing several code brackets from around the offending location, but the problem seems to be occuring around line 14 which is the same line the `else` statement is below. I am currently using Notepad++ to edit this file and so I have a way to see where eah code block starts and finishes by highlighting any `{` or `}` and it will highlight the respective beginning or end and there are no orphans here. I just don't understand why I'm getting this error.

This error is causing my scripting to not appear if there is anything in the $_GET array, which causes problems.

Comment: Can't exactly tell since your formatting is a bit off, but it looks like you are trying to do a "while" with an else. That's not a valid php control structure. I also recommend looking into using something that will point out syntax errors like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Since it's a javascript error instead of a PHP error, look at the source code in the browser to see what's being generated.

Comment: @patricksweeney The else statement is a continuation of the if statement on line 3. The while is enclosed within the if statement.

Comment: Like I said, I couldn't exactly tell since the formatting in your post was off.

Comment: @aynber It does appear to be the javasccript code! I've a feeling the app I was using added a spare one for me! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have problem with spaces in string 13.

```
echo "<table class='norm' border='1'><tr><th>" . $r[1] . "</th></tr><tr><td>$" . $r[2] . "</td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' id='u0name' placeholder='Adjust " . $r[1] . "s Cash' onKeyPress='preupd(event, " . $r[1] . ")' /></td></tr></table>";
```

I coped your code and detected spaces between $r and [1] on third and fourth possitions. And there are spaces in some other places.

Comment: I missed that, damn phone editors! i have now amended the code as it should be, however, I am still receiving the exact same error code for the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have `while`, `else`. `else` does not work with `while`.  If this is a mistake, then try removing the closing bracket just above the while loop. If this does not work how you intended it to, then you may need to restructure your code a little.

Comment: The else is for the if on line 3. The while is completely closed within the if.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies, I misread your code. I believe ALexander has the correct option.